# Parallel transmission lines impedance

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, transmission, line

I just want to know the correct way to calculate \$Z_{in}\$ in this network. It's very simple but I think I might be doing something wrong. Is it ok to calculate the impedance over one line and get \$Z_{in,1}\$ and the same way for \$Z_{in,2}\$?. That way we get the same on both of them so \$Z_{in}\$ should then be just the half of \$Z_{in,1}\$ because they are in parallel.

[image]

Ok, just to clarify, the overlapping lines are lines that go from the impedance \$Z_1\$ and form two parallel transmission lines so on both sides we have transmission lines with length \$ \frac{\lambda}{4} \$ (quarter wave transformer) with a line impedance of \$ Z_{L}\$. How can i calculate \$ Z_{in}\$ correctly in this problem.

Comment: Your diagram makes no sense - can you edit to explain what is intended by the overlapping lines? The model we call a Transmission Line is an approximation to reality. It is very good for coax, and pretty good for a 2-wire line, if the spacing is << $\lambda$ and it is kept away from conductors and dielectrics. For circuit analysis sanity we draw transmission lines as 2 wires with a Z0, but it's not like a scale drawing of the wires. Your diagram looks like a more general problem, TL approximations don't apply. It's more like an antenna circuit, best solved by simulation with a MoM algorithm.